# autoconf: do AC_RUN_IFELSE in сase of native compilation, otherwise AC_COMPILE_IFELSE

Tags: autotools

There is modified configrue.ac from rsync:

```
if test x"$host_cpu" = x"x86_64"; then
    if test x"$host_cpu" = x"$build_cpu"; then
        AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
/* some long C++ code here */
]], [[if (test_ssse3(42) != 42 || test_sse2(42) != 42 || test_avx2(42) != 42) exit(1);]])],[CXX_OK=yes],[CXX_OK=no])
    else
        AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
/* the same C++ code again */
]]),[CXX_OK=yes],[CXX_OK=no])
    fi
fi
```

How could this be improved? Is there a way to avoid duplicating C++ code?

Comment: You don't need to run a program. `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` is sufficient with: `#if !defined (__AVX2__)` ... `#error "fail"` ... `#endif` : if the compilation fails, `__AVX2__` is not a predefined macro - which is supported by gcc, clang, icc, msvc - AFAIK - given the correct ISA flags via `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`, etc.

Comment: @BrettHale, rsync maintainer insists on run-time tests https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/pull/104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid duplicating C++ code?

Sure.  Autoconf is, after all, fundamentally a macro language.  Instead of duplicating code, you can define and (re)use a macro that expands to that code.  Either [`AC_DEFUN()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Macro-Definitions.html) or `m4_define()` will serve, but the former is a bit overkill for what I think you want.  So,

```
m4_define([_EDO1_LONG_CODE], [[
// long C++ code ...
]])
```

You'll want to take a bit of care with quoting when you use it.  You are using double-quoting to ensure that the program source is not subject to macro expansion, but where you actually *want* macro expansion, you'll need to reduce the quotation level by one, something like this:

```
if test x"$host_cpu" = x"x86_64"; then
    if test x"$host_cpu" = x"$build_cpu"; then
        AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
]_EDO1_LONG_CODE], [[if (test_ssse3(42) != 42 || test_sse2(42) != 42 || test_avx2(42) != 42) exit(1);]])],[CXX_OK=yes],[CXX_OK=no])
    else
        AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
]_EDO1_LONG_CODE]),[CXX_OK=yes],[CXX_OK=no])
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You are right, quoting was the issue. It works for me in the form  `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([VAR])],…)`